# Finding arguments that go with methods in C++ dll's

Tags: c++, dll, signature, name-mangling, dumpbin

Ok, so I can use dumpbin.exe /exports library.dll to find all methods in the dll.

...but how do I find out which arguments to pass into them? Without a header file of course.

Comment: similar question: [Call function in c++ dll without header](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/554551/call-function-in-c-dll-without-header)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

For the usual C-style exports (e.g., Windows API DLLs): You can't. This information is not stored in the DLL and is inevitably lost after compilation (unless you have the headers or debuging symbols).

C++ exports, on the other hand, store their signature as part of the mangled function name and you can view them using Dependency Walker or similar tools, or demangle them manually using [the UNDNAME tool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx) or [DUMPBIN's `/SYMBOLS` option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b842y285.aspx).

Comment: Ahh sweet. Thanks. But ... how do I decipher the names?
For example these method names:
?GetCpuSpeed@@YAHXZ
?GetCpuSpeed@CDLL1@@QAEHXZ

Any ideas?

Comment: At least Dependency Walker is able to demangle the names via some menu entry. For detailed information, see the "External links" section of http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling

Comment: More links: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5x49w699.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b06ww5dd.aspx