# What functions does a C library export?

Tags: c++, c, dll, shared-libraries

If I take a C or C++ library in Windows, Linux or Mac, is there any way to know what functions and data structures it exports and their signatures without having documentation of this library?

Comment: What do you mean by "export"? Symbols visible to the linker or identifiers declared in a header?

Comment: That kind of depends. If you have headers for it (for one example) that will tell you functions and structrues (but not necessarily much about how to use them). If you just have the library proper (.lib, .a, .so, etc.) then you can usually get a fair amount of information for C++ (based on name mangling) but much less for C (since it doesn't normally use name mangling).

Comment: considering that the linker can check it, the answer must logically be "yes" (although not necessarily full info on the data structures). that's trivial logic. are you asking for specifics of the ways? in that case, please do supply details of the kinds of libraries and the specific toolchains.

Comment: There are tools to inspect what a `.dll` exports, yes. You may want to check the [Dependency Walker tool](http://www.dependencywalker.com/) for instance.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print a list of symbols exported from a dynamic library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4506121/how-to-print-a-list-of-symbols-exported-from-a-dynamic-library)

Comment: @Jongware: This question appears to include static libraries as well.

Answer (score 6):

You can definitely list the symbol names used by the linker.  For C++, this is a complete (mangled) signature.  For C (also applies to `extern "C"` in C++), it's often little more than the bare name (sometimes the total size of arguments, but without types, size of each, or even the number of arguments).

On Unix systems, the tool you want is `nm` (or `objdump`, which can additionally show symbols without linkage).  On Windows, `DUMPBIN /EXPORTS`.

If trying to inspect static libraries, you may have to extract them first (`ar` on Unix, `lib.exe` on Windows) and call `nm` or `dumpbin` on the individual members (object files).

See this related question for details about getting the C++ signatures: [Finding arguments that go with methods in C++ dll's](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3229333/103167)

Debug information may also provide access to C linkage signatures, since they aren't stored in the symbol table.

Comment: The OS X command (which is most likely for what OP calls "Mac") is `nm` as well.

Comment: @Jongware: OS X and Linux are both Unixy systems (OS X is BSD).

Comment: The OP seems unaware of that.

Comment: @Jongware: An Apple II is not a Macintosh.  There were, however, System 7, Mac OS 8, Mac OS 9 prior to the adoption of BSD with OS X.  (I think those were NeXt-based?)

Comment: Yah, sorry 'bout that - realized it too late. Still, OP ought to write "OS X" instead of "Mac". I's a bit like "I have an IBM at home", meaning a - Windows compatible - PC. (Even the word "PC" is not politically correct anymore.)