# Read exported functions with parameters from dmcmnutils.dll

Tags: c#, dllimport, unmanaged

I want to use `DmGetAadUserToken` function from `dmcmnutils.dll` in my .net code. But, unfortunately i didn't find any documentation for this function. Is there any way to extract method name with parameter details or any better way to find documentation for this function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to export the functions just. This should help :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438900/how-to-view-dll-functions

Comment: This will just list down the function names not parameter details @Ben

Comment: I assume you mean specifically a C library then, you will have to decompile it and see what the machine code is doing. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3229333/finding-arguments-that-go-with-methods-in-c-dlls

Comment: I would recommend using IDA for this. I've used it before and it worked well. Youll see it loading bytes in and whatnot in the source just look at the length of data and you can workout the type it expects. Its a very slow process though especially if its got function pointers or anything similar, hopefully its just ints etc...

Comment: If you don't know how to use this function, how do you know this function?

Comment: dumpbin /exports dmcmnutils.dll using command. @shingo